# How to create a power bi table having value corresponding to maximum hour and maximum date of each month present in another table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a csv file which records the quantity of available phones in a particular office at each hour of the day for every month, for every year.

```
PhoneID | Region | year | MonthYear | dateOnly | time | Quantity
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 02:00:00 | 99
......
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 87
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 87
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 99
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 02:00:00 | 100
......
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
......
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
......
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 23:00:00 | 90
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 98
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
3 | NorthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/28/2022 | 23:00:00 | 80
....
3 | NorthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/2/2023 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
3 | NorthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/25/2023 | 23:00:00 | 100
```

This a snippet for phone ID 3 for only 1 region. There are many regions and many phone ids in the dataset. Phone ID 3 is present in regions North Pole. South Pole has Phone IDs 5, 8.

I have to create a new table in power bi that would show - for every region, the quantity value of the maximum hour (last hour) on the maximum day (last day) of every month in every year.

So expected table would be like -

```
 Region | Year | MonthYear | Quantity
North Pole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 90  (90 was the quantity on 31st january 23:0:00)
North Pole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 80  (80 was the quantity on 28th February 23:0:00)
....
NorthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 100   (100 was the quantity on 25th August 23:0:00)
```

Since last record was taken at 25th August 2023, so maximum date taken for August is 25th August.

Since South Pole has ids 5,8, the quantities of 31st January 23:00:00 will be added up as (60+80) = 140, and then displayed

My attempts so far -
I am able to get the quantity value for maximum hour (23:00:00) for each date, using the below formula.

```
NewTable = 
 SUMMARIZE(
     FILTER(Data,Data[time]=MAX(Data[time])),
     Data[Region],
     Data[year],
     Data[MonthYear],
     Data[dateOnly],
     Data[time],
     "Quantity",
     SUM(Data[Quantity])
 )
```

This gives me the quantity value on maximum time (23:00:00) for every date.
But I need to get the on maximum time (23:00:00) on maximum day for every month.

I tried this one below, but it gave me only the values of Aug-2023, not the rest months.

```
NewTable = 
 SUMMARIZE(
     FILTER(Data,Data[dateonly]=MAX(Data[dateonly]) && Data[time]=MAX(Data[time])),
     Data[Region],
     Data[year],
     Data[MonthYear],
     Data[dateOnly],
     Data[time],
     "Quantity",
     SUM(Data[Quantity])
 )
```

Kindly help me in figuring out the correct formula that will create the desired table.

EDIT -

As mentioned earlier South Pole has Phone Ids 5 and 8.

```
PhoneID | Region | year | MonthYear | dateOnly | time | Quantity
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 02:00:00 | 99
......
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 87
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 87
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 99
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 02:00:00 | 100
......
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
......
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
......
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 23:00:00 | 90
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 98
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
5 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/28/2022 | 23:00:00 | 80
....
5 | SouthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/2/2023 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
5 | SouthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/25/2023 | 23:00:00 | 100
....
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 02:00:00 | 99
......
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 87
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 85
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 99
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 02:00:00 | 100
......
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
......
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 01:00:00 | 79
......
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 1/31/2022 | 23:00:00 | 90
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/1/2022 | 23:00:00 | 98
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 00:00:00 | 100
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 01:00:00 | 100
.....
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/2/2022 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
8 | SouthPole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 2/28/2022 | 23:00:00 | 82
....
8 | SouthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/2/2023 | 23:00:00 | 100
...
8 | SouthPole | 2023 | Aug-2023 | 8/25/2023 | 23:00:00 | 50
```

Then expected table should have -

```
Region | Year | MonthYear | Quantity
South Pole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 90
South Pole | 2022 | Jan-2022 | 90
South Pole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 80
South Pole | 2022 | Feb-2022 | 82
```

So, for each ID, each value is written. You can also include an extra column called Phone ID to indicate what quantity belongs to what ID

```
ID | Region | Year | MonthYear | Quantity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this DAX after running 'New Table' Command:

```
Result = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
SUMMARIZE(
DATA,
DATA[Region],
DATA[year],
DATA[MonthYear]),
"MaxHour",CALCULATE(MAX(DATA[time])),
"MaxDate",CALCULATE(MAX(DATA[dateOnly]))
)
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
    TblSummary,
    "Qty_Max",CALCULATE(SUM(DATA[Quantity]),FILTER(DATA,DATA[time] = [MaxHour] && DATA[dateOnly] = [MaxDate])
))
```

If we check the result, It gives us:

[image: MAX_HOUR_ANALYTICS]

Update2:

In that case, This is the DAX code you need to use:

```
Result = 
VAR TblSummary = ADDCOLUMNS(
SUMMARIZE(
DATA,
DATA[Region],
DATA[PhoneID],
DATA[year],
DATA[MonthYear]),
"MaxHour",CALCULATE(MAX(DATA[time])),
"MaxDate",CALCULATE(MAX(DATA[dateOnly])),
"MaxPhoneID",CALCULATE(MAX(DATA[PhoneID]))
)
RETURN
    ADDCOLUMNS(
    TblSummary,
    "Qty_Max",CALCULATE(SUM(DATA[Quantity]),FILTER(DATA,DATA[time] = [MaxHour] && DATA[dateOnly] = [MaxDate] && DATA[PhoneID] = [MaxPhoneID])
))
```

Resultset:

[image: SWEQ]

Small Description : ADDCOLUMNS is an iterator. It creates a row context, and evaluates its expression in this row context. Calculate makes the context transition, and transforms row context into filter context, and in this filter context we need to use MAX(DATA(PhoneID)) to get the concerned row.

As a beginner, you need to visit sqlbi.com and learn about iterators, context transition, row context, grouping logic (summarize) and many more. As you might guess, It will be impossible to explain all details without somebody not understanding these concepts.I wish you every success on your learning path

I hope It clarifies the situation for you!I appreciate your willingness and enthusiasm to be proficient at DAX :):):)

Comment: Thank you. It works for 1 ID in 1 region. Can you please tell me the expression to use for many Ids in a region? I have included an example case in edited section. The dataset keeps updating every week. 1 region can have many Ids and 1 Id can be present in many regions too.

Comment: You're welcome! I updated my solution. Please check the bottom part for recommended solution.

Comment: Thank you. For the data present till now, the updated DAX expression is working. Since I am a beginner in power bi, can you please explain, how MAX(DATA(PhoneID)) works and produces the desired result?

Comment: @MVKXXX I added a small explanation at the end of my post. Please check it.